# Entity framework 2.0 does not support DNX version 5.0

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting following error while trying to add EntityFramework to my WebAPI project
Entity framework 2.0 does not support DNX version 5.0

```
      "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

[image]
Any idea why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well considering you are still using a .json config its time for you to upgrade to 2017 Community Edition at minimum.  DNX has been dead for quite some time not to mention your 1.0 references.... Nothing listed is supported any longer due to age and beta